# In Landau & Lifshitz's 'Theory of elasticity' why $\sigma_{ik}=0$ on the surface for an infinite medium?

Tags: thermodynamics, tensor-calculus, elasticity, continuum-mechanics

It is not clear to me why considering an infinite medium we can consider $\sigma_{ik}=0$. Herewith the section is attached:
[image]

Comment: Because they consider that that surface at infinity is not deformed.

Comment: And why $\sigma_{ik}$  is not equal to zero also in the volume integral?

Comment: because you are here deforming the body here and not at infinity

Answer (score 0):

You want the energy of the deformation to be finite, this implies that the function $\sigma_{ik}$ has 0 as a limit when $r$ tends to infinity. Being more strict you want the density energy function to drop to 0, that is,

$$\lim_{r \rightarrow \infty} \sigma_{ik} u_{ki} = 0\, .$$

This is a necessary (although not sufficient) condition for

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^3} \sigma_{ik} u_{ki} < \infty\, ,$$

that is the condition for the finiteness of the total elastic energy on the body.